# popover with ng-repeat data not showing after ng-click

Tags: jquery, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, popover

I have a button to show a popover with loaded data from the server:

```
<button ng-click="main.getFieldDescriptions()" data-placement="bottom"
        data-toggle="popover" data-container="body"/>
```

This is an element I want to show as the popover content:

```
<div id="field-descriptions" class="hide" style="width:500px">
    <div class="row" ng-repeat="f in main.fieldDescriptions">
        <input class="form-control" readonly="true" value="{{f.fieldName}}" />
    </div>
</div>
```

The data is coming from the server with a get rest request(here is what I have in the controller)

```
angular.element("#show-fields-description").popover({
    html: true,
    content: function () {
        return angular.element("#field-descriptions").html();
    }
});

this.getFieldDescriptions = function getFieldDescriptions() {
    if (self.report.sysparm_table) {
        return server.get(url)
            .then(function getData(response) {
                self.fieldDescriptions = response.result;
            });
    }
    return null;
};
```

When the button is clicked popover shows empty content, by the second click it shows the popover with data. It seems popover shows first, then the server values load.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are mixing plane bootstrap popover with angularjs...so $apply/digest cycle of angularjs does not know it.

### There are many ways.

1. Call $apply when modal loaded
2. Instead of data-toggle on html, call `.popover('show')` in ng-click callback
3. use angular ui bootstrap popover

### For the first one:

```
$('#show-fields-description').on('shown.bs.popover', function () {
  main.getFieldDescriptions();

  //Need to call $scope.$apply() after data is there
})
```

### For the second one:

Please see this https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/components/popovers/#options

remove all other attributes from html:

```html
<button ng-click="main.getFieldDescriptions()"></button>
```

```
angular.element("#show-fields-description").popover({
    html: true,
    content: function () {
        return angular.element("#field-descriptions").html();
    },
    container: 'body',
    trigger: 'manual',
    placement: 'bottom'
});
```

and then call show/toggle here:

```
this.getFieldDescriptions = function getFieldDescriptions() {
    if (self.report.sysparm_table) {
        return server.get(url)
        .then(function getData(response) {
            self.fieldDescriptions = response.result;
            angular.element("#show-fields-description").popover('show');
        });
    }
    return null;
};
```

Comment: I think the second solution is the best in my case, could you add more detail about it

Comment: I used the second approach, again it shows the empty popup first then by next click it shows data.